# Native client driver DSN changes to SQL Server Driver

Tags: sql, client, express, native, dsn

I configured 4 DSNs using the SQL Native Client driver on a Windows 2003 R2 machine. 2 DSNs pointing to an SQL Server 2005 express databses in the same machine, & 2 pointing to databases in another machine.

Problem I am facing is that in the ODBC Admin tool, 1 of the DSNs shows as anSQL Server type DSN automatically.

How is this possible?

Does it indicate a corrupt SQL system?